# DataTemplates on collections

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a custom control class here named DockGroup. I would like to apply a style template for the DockGroup and databind to the Items dependency property (with a custom datatemplate).

```
[ContentProperty(@"Items")]
public class DockGroup : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>), typeof(DockGroup), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<UIElement>)));

    public ObservableCollection<UIElement> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<UIElement>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public DockGroup()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<UIElement>();
        DataContext = Items;
    }
}
```

Here is the style for the DockGroup, also contains the DataTemplate.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DockGroup}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Items" DataType="{x:Type UIElement}">
            <Label>I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT IN DATATEMPLATE</Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DockGroup}">
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="{Binding}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is a sample XAML that I would like to test with.

```
<local:DockGroup>
     <Label Background="#FFF0F077">Hello World!</Label>
     <Label Background="#FFF0F077">Hello World 2!</Label>
</local:DockGroup>
```

When I run the project, I get a blank window. And, I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: first of all , how do the labels know that they are the content of the DockGroup 

maybe  :  

<DockGroup.Items>
    <Label />
    <Label />
</DockGroup.Items>

Comment: The `ContentPropertyAttribute` for `DockGroup` specifies that any elements under `<DockGroup>` should be added to the `Items` Property (which is a collection, meaning it will allow multiple elements under `DockGroup`).

Comment: DataTemplate is suppose to be for something logical not a UIElement
for example a Class "Person" can have a DataTemplate which Describes 
its look and feel  .. it seems like  your trying to apply DataTemplates for Labels

Comment: iv'e tried some things but nothing seems to be working ... 
first you need to add a Static Ctor removing all the default MetaData

 static DockGroup()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DockGroup), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DockGroup)));                    
        }

iv'e tried also deriving from items control and giving it an itemtemplate ... 

it's just kinda wierd that your replacing a UIElement with anouther UIElement ...

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure nothing seems to be working.

Comment: i bet if you define the label as ItemsSource it might 
but that's only if your deriving from ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

You can style your control using an ItemsControl to make it work:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DockGroup}">
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```